# bash assign variable to another after operation

Tags: bash

I'm trying to print domain and topLeveldomain variables (example.com)

```
 $line = example.com

 domain =$line | cut -d. -f 1
 topLeveldomain = $line | cut -d. -f 2
```

However when I try and echo $domain, it doesn't display desired value

```
test.sh: line 4: domain: command not found
test.sh: line 5: topLeveldomain: command not found
```

Comment: be cautious with spaces before '='

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest:

```
line="example.com"

domain=$(echo "$line" | cut -d. -f 1)
topLeveldomain=$(echo "$line" | cut -d. -f 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove spaces around `=`:

```
line=example.com     # YES
line = example.com   # NO
```

When you create a variable, do not prepend `$` to the variable name:

```
line=example.com     # YES
$line=example.com    # NO
```

When using pipes, you need to pass standard output to the next command. Than means, you usually need to `echo` variables or `cat` files:

```
echo $line | cut -d. -f1    # YES
$line | cut -d. -f1         # NO
```

Use the `$()` syntax to get the output of a command into a variable:

```
new_variable=$(echo $line | cut -d. -f1)    # YES
new_variable=echo $line | cut -d. -f1       # NO
```

Comment: See: [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](http://stackoverflow.com/a/673940/3776858)

Comment: @Cyrus: thanks for pointing that out. Corrected (and learned). ^^

Answer (score 1):

The right code for this should be:

```
line="example.com"

domain=$(echo "$line" | cut -d. -f 1)
topLeveldomain=$(echo "$line" | cut -d. -f 2)
```

Consider the right syntax of bash:

```
variable=value
```

(there are no blanks allowed)

if you want to use the content of the variable you have to add a leading $
e.g.

```
echo $variable
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need external tools for this, just do this in `bash`

```
$ string="example.com"

# print everything upto first de-limiter '.'
$ printf "${string%%.*}\n"          
example

# print everything after first de-limiter '.'
$ printf "${string#*.}\n"           
com
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use AWK:

```
domain="abc.def.hij.example.com"
awk -F. '{printf "TLD:%s\n2:%s\n3:%s\n", $NF, $(NF-1), $(NF-2)}' <<< "$domain"
```

*Output*

```
TLD:com
2:example
3:hij
```

In the command above, `-F` option specifies the field separator; `NF` is a built-in variable that keeps the number of input fields.

**Issues with Your Code**

The issues with your code are due to invalid syntax.

> To set a variable in the shell, use
>
> `VARNAME="value"`
>
> Putting spaces around the equal sign will cause errors. It is a good
>   habit to quote content strings when assigning values to variables:
>   this will reduce the chance that you make errors.

Refer to the [Bash Guide for Beginners](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_02.html#sect_03_02_02).

Answer (score 0):

this also works:

```
 line="example.com"
 domain=$(echo $line | cut -d. -f1)
 toplevel=$(cut -d. -f2 <<<$line)
 echo "domain name=" $domain
 echo "Top Level=" $toplevel
```

You need to remove $ from line in the beginning, correct the spaces and echo $line in order to pipe the value to cut . Alternatively feed the cut with $line.